# AIR- changing alpha or visibility of StageWebView instance

Tags: actionscript-3, air, stagewebview

Using this class to wrap a StageWebView instance order to add it to the displaylist

http://soenkerohde.com/2010/11/air-mobile-stagewebview-uicomponent/

However, no matter what I try, I am still unable to control the alpha or visibility of the StageWebView instance.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: stagewebview is not a UIcomponent. So, You will not be able to control the alpha or the visibility. try stageWebView.stage and set values on it.

Comment: Thanks, will try stageWebView.stage. If you looked at the code you would see that UIComponent is used simply as a wrapper. And I thought the purpose was to be able to treat StageWebView as though it was part of the display list. Maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control visibility by setting it = null, but its an on-off option. No change in alpha is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can't. And you can't even place some DisplayObject over StageWebView, and animate It's alpha to imitate appearance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to display a web page with alpha by [rendering the StageWebView to a Bitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html#drawViewPortToBitmapData()) then draw the bitmap on screen with the required alpha.

Of course, no user interactions are possible while the view is displayed this way. But when you just want to create "show / hide" animations or you don't need the user to interact with the StageWebView, then it's fine.